# Pass Value of JavaScript Function(html2canvas) to Laravel Blade Form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I need to capture a screenshot from an HTML element and then upload that screenshot as an image file. I am able to capture a screenshot of an html element using [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). I have not been able to figure out how to pass the value from the onClick function to a Laravel Blade Form.

Everything else in Laravel is set up correctly(model, controller, migration, etc) as I have other forms that persist image files to the database.

### Laravel Blade View:

```
<div id="screenshot>
    <h1>capture this text</h1>
</div>
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action' => 'PhotosController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        // TODO: this input will receive the value from the JS function
        {!! Form::hidden('photo_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create Property', ['onClick' => 'takeScreenShot()', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

### JavaScript (html2canvas)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.takeScreenShot = function() {

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            // TODO: pass this variable to the form
            var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            //download(screenshot, "image_captured", "image/png");
        },
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Something like `document.getElementById('photo_id').value = screenshot` should get the variable assigned to the hidden input in your form. Place that right after `var screenshot = ...`. Or replace that line with `document.getElementById('photo_id').value = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

Comment: You can use ajax for this. in screenshot variable you are getting dataurl of screenshot, you can post it to server using ajax and save it on server

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var element = $('.content-wrapper');

$('#saveReport').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas(element, {
        background: '#ffffff',
        onrendered: function(canvas){
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'route-url',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    base64data: imgData
                }
            });
            alert('Success!');
            console.log(imgData);
        }
    });
});
```